# Match substring of a substring

Tags: php, regex

Input:

```
Animal {cow.<span>moo</span>} <span>noises</span>
```

Output:

```
Animal {cow.moo} <span>noises</span>
```

How could I match only the `<span>` inside the braces for replacement?
I have got as far as matching everything between the braces with

```
(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `preg_replace_callback` to match the strings in between `{...}` with a basic regex like `'~{[^}]+}~'` and then replace what you need inside the callback function:

```
$s = 'Animal {cow.<span>moo</span>} <span>noises</span>';
echo preg_replace_callback('~{[^}]+}~', function($m) {
    return str_replace(["<span>", "</span>"], "", $m[0]);
}, $s);
// => Animal {cow.moo} <span>noises</span>
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2UOZQG).

You may use a `preg_replace` inside the callback function if you need to replace with a regex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the `moo` inside the `span` for substitution you can use this regexp:

```
\{.*?\<span\>(.*)\<\/span\>\}
```

Here is an example: https://regex101.com/r/ryP3Y6/1

If you want to delete the `<span>` tags you can use:

```
(.*\{.*?)(?:\<[\/]?span\>)(.*)(?:<\/span\>)(\}.*)
```

And use `\1\2\3` for substitution:

Check: https://regex101.com/r/qECuai/1

Answer (score 0):

With a `\G` based pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|{)[^}]*?\K</?span>~', '', $str);
```

This pattern starts with two possible branches:

- the second branch is the one that matches first, starts with a { to ensure you are inside curly brackets. Note that you can add `(?=[^}]*})` after it to ensure there's a closing bracket.
- the first branch starts with `\G` that is the position after the last match.

`[^}]*?` forbids to go out of the curly bracket enclosed substring.

This design ensures that all series of matches starting from a { are contiguous and that the `<span>` tags found are between curly brackets.

---

For small strings and if you are sure curly brackets are balanced and not nested, you can also use a more simple pattern:

```
$str = preg_replace('~</?span>(?=[^{}]*})~', '', $str);
```